# NameError: name 'Logi' is not defined with Sikuli

Tags: sikuli

I'm just trying Sikuli. I'm trying to have a "main" page that call others files containing some classes and some def. But I get following error:

[error] Arrêté [error] Une erreur est survenue à la ligne 13 [error] Message d'erreur : Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\Users\gregory\AppData\Local\Temp\sikuli-tmp2607956245912033896.py", line 13, in    log = Logi() NameError: name 'Logi' is not defined

I don't really know why.

My Code

main.sikuli

```
# Path to def
myScriptPath = "C:\\NOT_SCANNED\\Stockage\\SikuliProject\\"

if not myScriptPath in sys.path: sys.path.append(myScriptPath)

# Import File.sikuli
from loginLogout import *
from sikuli.Sikuli import *

# Call Def
if __name__ == "__main__":
    log = Logi()
    log.login()
    log.logout()
```

loginLogout.sikuli

```
from sikuli.Sikuli import *

class Logi:
def login(self):
    openApp("MyApp")
    wait(5)
    type("demo" + Key.TAB + "demo" + Key.TAB)
    type("a", KEY_CTRL)
    type("localhost")
    click( )
    wait(5)
    wait( )
```

I noticed someting. IF I named my class foo it works. I don't really understand.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

OK I found something. I made something wrong with naming my files. Problem seems to have been fixed with made a save as and now I do not have this problem anymore. But I have another one. Now I did not get any error when I execute it but nothing is executed ...

New code:

main

```
# -*-coding:Latin-1 -*

   # Path to def
   myScriptPath = "C:\\NOT_SCANNED\\Stockage\\SikuliProject"

   if not myScriptPath in sys.path: sys.path.append(myScriptPath)

   # Import File.sikuli from sikuli.Sikuli import * from Logi import *

   # Call Def
   if __name__ == "__main__":   
    log = Logi()
    log.login
```

Logi

```
from sikuli.Sikuli import *

class Logi:

  def login(self):
    openApp("MYAPP")
    wait(5)
    type("demo" + Key.TAB + "demo" + Key.TAB)
    type("a", KEY_CTRL)
    type("localhost")
    click( )
    wait(5)
    wait( )

  def logout(self):
    click( )
    wait( )
    click( )

  def openNewTab(self):
    click( )

  def createNewSingle(self):
    click( )
    click( )
    rightClick( )
    click( )
    click( )
    wait( )
    click( )
    type("test")
    click( )
    type("this is a test with Sikuli")
    click( )
    rightClick( )
    click( )
    click( )
    wait( )
    click( )
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: You also can use a raw string for `myScriptPath `. For example: `myScriptPath = r"C:\NOT_SCANNED\Stockage\SikuliProject"` Then you don't have to escape backslahes etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the script path but not the script itself.  In your main add:

```
import Logi
reload(Logi)
```